# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to com.ree.kms.DakaHinbanClass

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-edittext

I want to add EditText to the listview, but I can't do it smoothly. Please guide. If it is List<String>, it is normal, but DakaHinbanClass is used, How to write code that uses Class

The data is obtained from MySQL, and the content can be displayed normally at present. I want to change the production quantity directly in the listview, but when running, the position of line 195 always reports an error.

ErrorCode:

`2022-03-31 15:58:14.780 13403-13403/com.ree.kms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main     Process: com.ree.kms, PID: 13403     java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableStringBuilder cannot be cast to com.ree.kms.DakaHinbanClass         at` **`com.ree.kms.DakaListAdapterClass$MyTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(DakaListAdapterClass.java:195)`**         `at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8336)         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4399)         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4247)         at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:90)         at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4222)         at com.ree.kms.DakaListAdapterClass.getView(DakaListAdapterClass.java:101)         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2474)         at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1920)         at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:717)         at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:778)         at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1701)         at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2235)         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5579)         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1189)         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5579)         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5579)         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5579)         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5579)         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5579)         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2740)         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16953)         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5579)         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2562)         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2265)         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1323)         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6718)         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:894)         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:696)         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)`

DakaListAdapterClass

```
package com.ree.kms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class DakaListAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {

    String contains1,contains2;
    Context context;
    List<DakaHinbanClass> valueList;
    private int mTouchItemPosition=-1;

    public DakaListAdapterClass(List<DakaHinbanClass> listValue,Context context){
        this.context = context;
        this.valueList = listValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.valueList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.valueList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewItem_Daka viewItem_daka = null;
        if (convertView == null){
            viewItem_daka = new ViewItem_Daka();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_daka,null);
            viewItem_daka.TextViewHinban = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daka_hinban);
            viewItem_daka.TextViewQuery = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daka_query);
            viewItem_daka.TextViewKyakusaki = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daka_kyakusaki);
            viewItem_daka.TextViewDate_End = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daka_date_end);
            viewItem_daka.TextViewRemarks = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daka_remarks);
            viewItem_daka.TextViewCyui = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daka_cyui);
            viewItem_daka.TextViewRakasu = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daka_rakasu);
            viewItem_daka.EditTextQuery_out = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_daka_query_out);

            viewItem_daka.EditTextQuery_out.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    mTouchItemPosition = (int) v.getTag();

                    if ((v.getId()==R.id.tv_daka_query_out && canVertivalScroll((EditText) v) )){
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            viewItem_daka.mTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher();
            viewItem_daka.EditTextQuery_out.addTextChangedListener(viewItem_daka.mTextWatcher);
            viewItem_daka.updatePosition(position);

            convertView.setTag(viewItem_daka);
        }else{
            viewItem_daka = (ViewItem_Daka) convertView.getTag();
            viewItem_daka.updatePosition(position);
        }

        viewItem_daka.TextViewHinban.setText("品番:"+valueList.get(position).Hinban);
        viewItem_daka.TextViewQuery.setText("着荷数:"+valueList.get(position).Query);
        viewItem_daka.TextViewKyakusaki.setText("取引先:"+valueList.get(position).Kyakusaki);
        viewItem_daka.TextViewDate_End.setText("完成予定:"+valueList.get(position).Date_end);
        viewItem_daka.TextViewRakasu.setText("落下数:"+valueList.get(position).Rakasu);

        viewItem_daka.EditTextQuery_out.setText(valueList.get(position).Query);
        viewItem_daka.TextViewRemarks.setText("備考:"+valueList.get(position).Remarks);
        viewItem_daka.TextViewStatus = valueList.get(position).Status;

        if (mTouchItemPosition==position){
            viewItem_daka.EditTextQuery_out.requestFocus();
            viewItem_daka.EditTextQuery_out.setSelection(viewItem_daka.EditTextQuery_out.getText().length());
        }else{
            viewItem_daka.EditTextQuery_out.clearFocus();
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(valueList.get(position).Cyui)){
            viewItem_daka.TextViewCyui.setText("注意:なし");
        }else {
            viewItem_daka.TextViewCyui.setText("注意:" + valueList.get(position).Cyui);
        }

        contains1= (String) viewItem_daka.TextViewCyui.getText();
        contains2= (String) viewItem_daka.TextViewStatus;
        if(contains1.equals("注意:なし")){
            viewItem_daka.TextViewCyui.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));

        }else{
            viewItem_daka.TextViewCyui.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }

        if (!contains2.contains("生産済")){
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_daka_background);
        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_chaka_background);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private boolean canVertivalScroll(EditText editText){
        int scrollY = editText.getScrollY();
        int scrollRange = editText.getLayout().getHeight();
        int scrollExtent = editText.getHeight() - editText.getCompoundPaddingTop() - editText.getCompoundPaddingBottom();
        int scrollDifference = scrollRange - scrollExtent;
        if (scrollDifference == 0){
            return false;
        }
        return (scrollY>0) || (scrollY < scrollDifference -1 );
    }
    class ViewItem_Daka {
        TextView TextViewHinban;
        TextView TextViewQuery;
        TextView TextViewDate_End;
        TextView TextViewKyakusaki;
        TextView TextViewCyui;
        TextView TextViewRemarks;
        TextView TextViewFusoku;
        TextView TextViewRakasu;
        EditText EditTextQuery_out;
        TextView TextViewQuery_out;
        String TextViewStatus;
        MyTextWatcher mTextWatcher;
        public void updatePosition(int position){
            mTextWatcher.updatePosition(position);
        }
    }

    class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{
        private int mPosition;
        public void updatePosition(int Position){
            mPosition = Position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            valueList.set(mPosition, (DakaHinbanClass) s);    ←error is here
        }
    }
}
```

DakaHinbanClass

```
package com.ree.kms;

public class DakaHinbanClass {
    public String HinbanId;
    public String Hinban;
    public String HangaNumber;
    public String Date_end;
    public String Query;
    public String Weight;
    public String WeightAll;
    public String Cyui;
    public String Query_out;
    public String Remarks;
    public String Kyakusaki;
    public String Status;
    public String Fusoku,Rakasu,FuryoHakuri,FuryoHaiki;
}
```

`@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { valueList.set(mPosition, s.toString());    ←That's not right }`

Comment: the `Edittable s` is the new String that you have edited. You can't cast it to a class. You should create a new DakaHinbanClass  with the new string and set it in the list

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I wrote a full answer down here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user changes the string inside the `EditText`, the method `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` is called, and `s` represents the new edited String. You want to update the **DakaHinbanClass** object inside the list, so you can't just conver a String an object (this String is only one class member of this object class, right?)

If you want to update the **Query** value inside this object, first get the object and then set the class member value to the new String, like this:

```
  @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

        DakaHinbanClass temp = valueList.get(mPosition);
        temp.Query = s.toString();
    }
```